# Use unaccent postgres extension in Knex.js Querys

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, unaccent

I need make a query for a postgresdb without identify accents (á, í,ö, etc).

I'm already use Knex.js as query builder, and postgresql have a unaccent extension that works fine in sql querys directly to db, but in my code i use knex and unaccent function throws error in querys.

Can anyone help me, ¿is possible make querys with knex.js that use unaccent function of postgresql?

Comment: If you tell what is the SQL you are trying to achieve and what kind of error you are getting it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to process the string before submitting the query using the following code:

```
const normalize = (str) => str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
console.log(normalize('Ấ Á Ắ Ạ Ê')) -> 'A A A A A'.
```

Or if you use postgresql version 13 or later it already supports that functionality.

```
select normalize('hồ, phố, ầ', NFC) → 'ho, pho, a' -- NFC (the default), NFD, NFKC, or NFKD.
```

Document: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html